# Write a SQL statement in Access 2010 VBA to retrieve contents of multi value field based on field value from a form

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

To me this should work, and I'm not sure why it's not.  Usually very good at working through this stuff, or scouring forums until I find the answer, or something that leads me to it.

```
Private Sub Command94_Click()

'Set SQL Statement
Dim strSQL As String
Dim strSQL1 As String

  strSQL = [Forms]![frmYMAD_Coordinator]![YMAD_Number]
  strSQL1 = "SELECT YMAD_Category.value " & _
            "FROM tblYMAD " & _
            "WHERE YMAD_Number = '" & strSQL & "' ;"

MsgBox (strSQL1)
End Sub
```

However, this is what I'm getting in my msgbox test:

SELECT YMAD_Category.[value] FROM tblYMAD WHERE YMAD_Number = '25' ;.

Now the field `YMAD_Category` is a multi-value field and `YMAD_Number` is a field in `tblYMAD` and also the name of the field on `frmYMAD_Coordinator`.

I'm obviously missing something here, but not sure what it is.  I can get a query to work in Access writing SQL in the Query Design View while pulling results from a multi-value field, but not in VBA.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What you get in the msgbox is what you should be getting based on your code. Is `YMAD_Number` a text field or a numerical one? If it is a numerical one then your problem is the use of single quotes.

Comment: `YMAD_Number` is a numerical field (_Autonumber_).   Let me remove the single quotes and see what happens.

Comment: `@SunKnight0`Didn't work.  Message box displays:  
  
SELECT YMAD_Category.value FROM tblYMAD WHERE YMAD_Number = 25 ;

Comment: Which is exactly what it is supposed to display. The `strSQL1` string. Because that's all it is up to that point, a string. What did you expect? If you want to display the query results you have a lot more work to do. You have to actually run the query, retrieve the resulting recordset and format it as a string before you can msgbox it...

Comment: @SunKnight0  Wow...do I feel dumb.  You are blatantly right.  I got it working and obviously needed to use `DoCmd.RunSQL`.  Boy do I feel sheepish, sorry for wasting your time.  Thanks for the singles quotes piece though.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
  strSQL1 = "SELECT " & YMAD_Category.value & _
        " FROM tblYMAD " & _
        "WHERE YMAD_Number = '" & strSQL & "' ;"
```

Besides, are you sure that `YMAD_Number` is a number stored as string?
If it's an Number, you might want to filter on `WHERE YMAD_Number = " & strSQL & ";"` without the single quotes `'` around the value.

Comment: `YMAD_Category` is a multi-value field, not a form field.